# Spring MVC 4 Java Config with Static HTML Views

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a single page HTML/Angular app backed by Spring MVC 4 without .jsp files.

When the user arrives to the root URL (http://myapp.com/ for example), I want to send the single page HTML document (index.html).

However, I am new to Spring MVC's Java config and cannot work out the proper combination of `ServletMapping`, `ViewResolver`, and `ResourceHandler`.

I know that there may be some additional configuration for the "default" or "index" page, but I may be mistaken.

So how do I make a Java configured Spring MVC 4 application send an html file?

File structure

```
/src
  '-/main
     |-/web-inf
     '-/webapp
         |-index.html (want to send this)
         '-/app
            |-/partials
            '-app.js
```

WebAppConfig.java

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/").addResourceLocations("/index.html");
}
```

IndexController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public void index() {

  System.out.println("pls"); // executes
  // Have tried returning "index" and "index.html"
}
```

WebInitializer.java

```
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
  // have tried with "/" as well
  return new String[] { "/*" };
}
```

Comment: In `ViewResolver` suffix `.html` should do the thing.

Comment: I tried to add `viewResolver.setSuffix(".html")` in the WebConfig but it did not work. I tried this by adding `return "index"` to the controller as well.

Comment: your solution should be added as an answer, not in the question itself

Comment: Made the change, @Brian_Clozel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few working solutions either way - in case anyone needs one for their specific use case.

**If you DO NOT want to invoke a controller method and just serve the file.**

WebInitializer.java:

```
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("index.html").addResourceLocations("/index.html    ");
}
```

**If you DO want to invoke a controller method on landing.**

No welcome file list is required in the web.xml

WebInitializer.java:

```
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/*" };
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("index.html").addResourceLocations("/index.html    ");
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>
```

in  your `dispathcer-servlet` file.

Comment: Hey @Sny786, I am not using .xml configuration. I would like to use pure Java configuration on this.

Comment: @Mac set Prefix property  to `/WEB-INF` in view resolver and try